# How can I create a moving average depending on today's date?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've got daily data sorted as:

```
     A           B          C               K
Date        | 1-1-2010 | 2-1-2010 | ... | Today
Production  |   750    |    0     | ... |   650
```

Day-Month-Year (formatted as date)

And what I need is to have a formula that will calculate the average for the last year as 365 days. That is from Today-364 to Today. But I need it to update itself based on the current day. So it should forget the last first number and add the latest one (assuming daily update of the data).

And to compare, the exact same formula but until Today - "X", referring "X" to a cell.

I though about something like
`AVERAGEIFS(B2:K2;B1:K1;">(TODAY()-365)";B1:K1;"(less than)TODAY()")`, but it causes a `#DIV/0!` error.

I had to write less than because text would disappear after the symbol.

How can I create a moving average depending on today's date?

Comment: What do you mean *"but it doesn't work"*? Do you get an error? Are the results wrong? What? Also, are the dates formatted as dates or text?

Comment: I get the Div/0 error. The dates as formatted as dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formula should instead look like this

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B2:K2,B1:K1,">"&TODAY()-365,B1:K1,"<"&TODAY())
```

When you write your criteria as `"<TODAY()"` you are telling Excel that `"<TODAY()"` is a string literal, so it won't calculate the TODAY() function.